# Eliminating a term of a superposition state

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-state, programming

Is there a way of eliminating a term of a superposition state?
Let's say I have the state

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|00\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|01\rangle + \frac{1}{2}|10\rangle$$

What operation would I do to eliminate the state $|00\rangle$? And be left with only the terms $|01\rangle + |10\rangle$. I'm looking for a general solution, an idea, rather than one specific to this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weeding out qubit states with leftmost qubit as 1](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/weeding-out-qubit-states-with-leftmost-qubit-as-1)

Comment: Also related to [Amplitude suppression](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6427/amplitude-suppression)

Answer (score 1):

If you've got

$$|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|00\rangle+\frac{1}{2} \Big( |01\rangle + |10\rangle \Big)$$

and you want to suppress state $|00\rangle$ using two ancillary qubits, you can

- apply a negated Toffoli gate to an ancillary qubit `q[2]` as target
- apply Hadamard to a second ancillary `q[3]`
- Toffoli $\mathbf{CCX}(q[2],q[3],q[0])$
- $\mathbf{X}(q[3])$
- $\mathbf{CCX}(q[2],q[3],q[1])$

and you'll obtain

$$|\Psi_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big( |01\rangle + |10\rangle \Big)$$

Simplyfing:

[image]

In general (if the state $|\Psi\rangle$ is not a simple superposition) you can use a negated Toffoli gate (or a series of $n-1$ negated Toffoli gates for an input register of $n$ qubits) to get the state $|00\rangle$ (or the state $|0\rangle^n$ for an input register of $n$ qubits) to an ancillary qubit (or $n-1$ ancillary qubits) and then suppress it to obtain the desired result (this depends on the result you want to obtain).